# How to remove border around UICollectionView in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I have made a `UICollectionView` in my project.It is custom `UICollectionViewCell`.When i run the app it shows the black border around the `UICollectionViewCell`.Please tell me how can i remove that border around the custom cell?

[image]

Comment: please post the screenshot and some code.

Comment: check my updated question.

Comment: Try `cell.layer.borderColor=[UIColor clearColor].CGColor;`

Comment: Can you post the code where you create the cell? Hard to know what happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UICollectionViewCell *cell = [[UICollectionViewCell alloc] init];
cell.layer.borderColor = (__bridge CGColorRef _Nullable)([UIColor clearColor]);
```

cell is a name given to Collection View cell element. This line of code will make the border color transparent.

Comment: how to do this in swift 3.0 ?

Comment: I haven't migrated to Swift.

Answer (score 0):

Swift 5 version

```
var cell = UICollectionViewCell()
cell.layer.borderColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
```

Tested the code in Swift 5